# Can any one tell me where the 4xp gap is coming from between my thumbnails?

Tags: css, thumbnails, space

I’m new to CSS and wondering if you can give me a little help.
I have been working through some tutorials and was having a little play with some popup images.

I can’t for the life of me work out where the 4px gap is coming from between the thumbnails.

I wanted to space my little gallery with a 12px margin between the coloured squares, but it moves about quite strangely when i add in my own margin. Am I just doing it in the wrong way?

I have all my code here http://jsfiddle.net/p45JH/5/

Here is the CSS code im using:-

```
.thumbnail {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
.thumbnail:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 50;
}
.thumbnail span {

    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 5px;
    left: -1000px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    visibility: hidden;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.thumbnail span img {

    border-width: 0;
    padding: 2px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
.thumbnail:hover span {

    visibility: visible;
    bottom: 35px;
    left: 35px;

}
```

I’m sure it’s really simple, just my limited knowledge stopping me from figuring it out.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using div instead of links, look if I remove the spaces between the links in the Html code : http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/p45JH/6/

**No spaces : (no padding/margin)**

```
<a href=""> </a><a href=""> </a>
```

**Spaces : (do a normal gap)**

```
<a href=""> </a>
<a href=""> </a>
```

Comment: i will have a play with this Monday when i get back....i never expected such a speedy respons! it looks to fix my problem.
thanks Alot

Answer (score 0):

It's whitespace.  Spaces between inline (and inline-*) elements are honored.  You can just comment them out:

```
<a class="thumbnail">...</a><!--
--><a class="thumbnail">...</a>
```

Or use one of the other techniques found here:  http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Thanks for the link and the posible soloution.
i'm absorbing as much info as possible at the mo, so that link looks excellent. Thanks again.